# getting an error while trying to use the namespace I created

Tags: php, namespaces

*script named tester.php*

```
<?php
namespace my;
class Tester {
    public function greet() {
        echo "Hello ! <br />";
    }
}
```

a new script named *tester1.php* :

```
<?php
use my;

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->greet();
```

When I run `tester1.php` I get this error:

```
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'my' has no effect
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tester_1.php on line 2

Fatal error: Class 'Tester' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tester_1.php on line 4
```

Why am I getting this error ? Both these scripts are in the same directory `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`use` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) is meant for aliasing a class/interface/namespace name, rather than importing a namespace so it can be used. To use your namespace, you just need to put `namespace my;` at the top of your `tester1.php` file (and also include the original file so that your class definition is available).

```
<?php
namespace my;
include("tester.php");

$obj = new Tester();
$obj->greet();
```

If you wanted to alias to another name, then you can use `use`, for example,

```
<?php
namespace my;
use my\Tester as Blah;
include("tester1.php");

$obj = new Blah();
$obj->greet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<?php use my as Something;`

this will work.

Complete code.

**First.php**

```
<?php namespace my;
use my as Blah;
include("second.php");
$obj = new Tester();
$obj->greet();
```

**second.php**

```
<?php namespace my;
class Tester {
    public function greet() {
        echo "Hello ! <br />";
    }
}
```

You need to declare `namespace` at stating before any of code including `doctype`